# '$path' not recognized as internal or external command when running up.ps1 for the getting started template sc 10

Tags: docker

**TLDR** I am getting `'$path' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` when running `up.ps1` in step 7 of `Create the MyProject solution` in the [Sitecore 10 Getting Started Template](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html).

The bit of code in question is in `docker/build/dotnetsdk/dockerfile`

```
# escape=`

# This is a custom SDK image based on servercore that serves two purposes:
#   * Allows us to build a mixed solution (framework and netcore)
#   * Allows us to run `dotnet watch` for rendering host development
#     (see https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1984)

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as netcore-sdk
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8

# Ensure updated nuget. Depending on your Windows version, dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 tag may provide an outdated client.
# See https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/1c3dd6638c6b827b81ffb13386b924f6dcdee533/4.8/sdk/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile#L7
# ENV NUGET_VERSION 5.8.0
# RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe"

# Retrieve .NET Core SDK
COPY --from=netcore-sdk ["/Program Files/dotnet/", "/Program Files/dotnet/"]

ENV `
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true `
    # Enable correct mode for dotnet watch (only mode supported in a container)
    DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true `
    # Skip extraction of XML docs - generally not useful within an image/container - helps performance
    NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip 

RUN $path = ${Env:PATH} + ';C:\Program Files\dotnet\;'; `
    setx /M PATH $path

# Trigger first run experience by running arbitrary cmd
RUN dotnet help | out-null
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

### Env

- Powershell running in admin, version 5.1.19041.610
- .Net Framework version 4.8.04084
- .Net core version 5.0.102
- Docker Desktop 3.1.0 (51484) with docker for windows enabled
- VS 2019 community

Output

```
.\up.ps1
Building containers...
traefik uses an image, skipping
Building solr
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> 81bd20568e21

Successfully built 81bd20568e21
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-solr:latest
Building mssql
Step 1/7 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/7 : ARG HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE
Step 3/7 : FROM ${HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE} AS headless_services
 ---> 2da0dc9f1eaf

Step 4/7 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> 6eb6bf976fcd
Step 5/7 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f7101fc97967
Step 6/7 : COPY --from=headless_services C:\module\db C:\jss_data
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4cac56a801cd
Step 7/7 : RUN C:\DeployDatabases.ps1 -ResourcesDirectory C:\jss_data;     Remove-Item -Path C:\jss_data -Recurse -Force;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6664ceb0ccfa

Successfully built 6664ceb0ccfa
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-mssql:latest
Building xconnect
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> 19d4466b0aed

Successfully built 19d4466b0aed
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-xconnect:latest
Building xdbautomationworker
Step 1/2 : ARG PARENT_IMAGE
Step 2/2 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
 ---> d65d7ab7640f

Successfully built d65d7ab7640f
Successfully tagged myproject-xp0-xdbautomationworker:latest
Building dotnetsdk
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as netcore-sdk
 ---> e82f832fabb2

Step 2/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8
 ---> af16f980b5a4
Step 3/6 : COPY --from=netcore-sdk ["/Program Files/dotnet/", "/Program Files/dotnet/"]
 ---> 1beb0b042fe0
Step 4/6 : ENV     DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true     DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true     NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip
 ---> Running in 172be5fe0676
Removing intermediate container 172be5fe0676
 ---> 039e64f7cf23
Step 5/6 : RUN $path = ${Env:PATH} + ';C:\Program Files\dotnet\;';     setx /M PATH $path
 ---> Running in 92c76af86598
'$path' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: Service 'dotnetsdk' failed to build : The command 'cmd /S /C $path = ${Env:PATH} + ';C:\Program Files\dotnet\;';     setx /M PATH $path' returned a non-zero code: 1
C:\dev\ScGettingStarted\MyProject\up.ps1 : Container build failed, see errors above.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\up.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,up.ps1
```

### Note

On a fresh install I was originally getting `Invoke-WebRequest is not recognized as an internal or external command` - but because I already had the correct nuget, I commented this line out.

Original error

```
Step 4/8 : RUN Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe"
 ---> Running in 09e5746490a3
'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR: Service 'dotnetsdk' failed to build : The command 'cmd /S /C Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your scripts are defaulting to use basic CMD as it's shell rather than what you expect; a powershell.

Add the following to your relevant docker files.

`SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]`

References:

- [PR that addresses the same problem you are experiencing](https://github.com/Sitecore/MVP-Site/commit/ae217535fa7a6716dc0016a450f78873e4729589)
- [Sitecore 10 - ASP.NET core rendering engine - Fix for Error - 'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://jitendrasoni.blogspot.com/2020/11/sitecore-10-aspnet-core-rendering.html)